How to differentiate between bareland and crop land while supervised classification?
I am performing supervised classification in Sentinel 2A 10m resolution image using Arcgis 10.5. The area for which I am doing classification mostly contains built up areas, very few bareland and I guess barely any crop land. However how do I accurately differentiate between bareland and cropland as they seem alike while I try to give training samples?

using timeseries satellite imagery PSETAE model https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/how-psetae-works/
